# Slim 3 method getUploadedFiles() returns an empty array

Tags: php, slim

When trying to mock a test with a test file I get stuck. Basically the `withUploadedFiles()` method wants me to work with an array.
As you can see down below, I try to `var_dump` to see if it has worked but in every case the array is empty. I wonder why this is?
If I only `var_dump` my array with the name `$uploadedFiles` it shows me the content.

Do you see where my mistake is?

```
<?php

use Slim\Http\UploadedFile;

class FileControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // ...

    public function testUserCanCreateAFileSuccessfullyWithStatusCode200()
    {
        // ...

        $uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(
            $directory . '/File_1.txt',
            'File_1.txt',
            'text/plain',
            filesize($directory . '/File_1.txt'),
            0
        );

        $uploadedFiles = array();
        $uploadedFiles["file"] = $uploadedFile;

        // ...

        $request = \Slim\Http\Request::createFromEnvironment($environment);
        $request->withUploadedFiles($uploadedFiles);    

        var_dump($request->getUploadedFiles());         // array(0) { }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requests are immutable, you always create a new instance when you manipulate it...

```
 $request = $request->withUploadedFiles($uploadedFiles);
```

Comment: You really have sharp eye-sight!